# Killing a thread or an asynchronous task

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin

let's say I use a jar that IBM has created. 
Let's say that this Jar has a function that I need but is ultimately build as such:

```
 while (true) {
     System.out.println(1)
 }
```

(of course it doesn't really just printing 1, but for the example let's say it is)
So, I made the call to the function that does it in another thread using future. How can I completely kill the thread that this code is running in? Or alternatively, how can I kill the asynchronous task in Kotlin that runs the code.

Solutions in Kotlin or Java will be great,
thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I've found out, that if this is a thread, I can `Thread#stop()` it to really make it stop. But unfortunately making the constructor throwing exceptions multiple times, causes the JVM to erase the class from memory causing a `NoClassDefFoundError` when instantiating the class the next time..

Comment: do you have provision to change `while (true)` condition?

Comment: You said you have `future`. Any issue calling `Future#cancel(true)` ?

Comment: @AmitBera No, I can't touch the code inside the function that does it.

Comment: @rkosegi I do call it, I even call ExecutorService#shutdownNow() function but the both of them cannot kill the thread.

Comment: `Thread#stop()` is your only option, but it a) is a crappy, leaky mechanism that can destabilize the whole application, b) may still fail to kill the thread because all it does is throw an exception in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you can capture it's thread you should be able to kill it so long as it is doing some kind of blocking function internally.

```
class OtherFunction implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // We assume the thread will exit when interrupted.
                System.out.println("Bye!!");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
}


class Killable implements Runnable {
    final Runnable target;
    private Thread itsThread;

    Killable(Runnable target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Catch the thread id of the target.
        itsThread = Thread.currentThread();
        // Launch it.
        target.run();
    }

    public void kill() {
        // Give it a good kick.
        itsThread.interrupt();
    }
}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    OtherFunction theFunction = new OtherFunction();
    Killable killableVersion = new Killable(theFunction);
    new Thread(killableVersion).start();
    // Wait for a few seconds.
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    // Kill it.
    killableVersion.kill();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will help the OP in this case: the method he's calling seems uninterruptible. OP mentions, in the question comments, of calling `future.cancel(true)` and `executor.shutdownNow()` which both attempt to cancel running tasks via interrupting the threads but the task keeps executing.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon the whole point is that I can't touch the code... It does not catch InterruptedException nor does it sleep. It's just as I wrote above,

Comment: @AntilKarev - This should catch any blocking code running in the thread. If there is no blocking then you are out of luck. Note that `System.out` and almost any `NIO` uses blocking code.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon that's why I ask of a way to completely kill the thread, no interrupt whatsoever, just kill it without notice.

Comment: This solution will work with `Thread#stop()` just the same. But `Thread#stop()` doesn't kill a thread, it just makes an exception appear in the code the thread is executing. A simple `catch (Throwable t)` is all it takes to block it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the Thread#stop() is deprecated. And it doesn't helps no more

Comment: @DiLDoST `Thread#stop()` has been deprecated since 1997 :) Almost nobody has ever had the opportunity to call this method in its non-deprecated state.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik did i say any different? Hope so not

Comment: @DiLDoST Yes, you said "it helps no more", which made it sound like something changed about `Thread.stop()` recently. However, this whole thread assumes the tacit knowledge that it is and has always been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `Thread#stop()` solved my problem. I know it's deprecated and can be prevented with `catch(Throwable t)` but at least it did the trick for me.

By the way, to get the thread from the executor, I've used `AtomicReference<Thread>` and set it in the callback.

Comment: Don't use `Thread#stop()`. Practically all programs that use it are invalid. It was deprecated in the release after it was added because it should never have existed. See my answer.

Comment: @Persixty yeah, Unfortunately the exception is thrown is a constructor, and the multiple constructor exceptions cause erasure of the class...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'erasure of the class' unless you mean throwing an exception in the constructor means results in not returning a fully constructed object. That's the right behaviour. You haven't provided enough about your use case to advise.

Comment: It means that the next time I try to instantiate a new instance of the MQQueueManager class, It results in NoClassDefError thrown

Comment: You're getting that because the classes aren't `Thread#stop()`-safe and you calling it is leaving them corrupt. Here's an example where a `ThreadDeath` is thrown into a constructor and corrupts the environment in an otherwise safe class. https://ideone.com/qUqn6R. But fear not there is a proper solution I understand correctly. There's limited space in these comments. I'll rough out the answer in the next comment. But your problem is really that the timeout is global. First thing is to confirm you can't locally override the setting. There may be obscure API for doing that. But if not...

Comment: You want to shorten or extend the timeout. Write a `Runnable` class that actually tries (and even keeps trying) to instantiate the class and run it in a parallel thread.
How does this help? The Runnable controls a running/succeeded/failed flag and uses `this.notify()` to indicate a change of status. The main thread uses wait(long timeout) using your preferred timeout to wait on notification. If your timeout expires you set an `AtomicBoolean` in the `Runnable` that tells the constructor to 'stop' cleanly. 100% safe and you have complete control over how long your main thread hangs around.

Comment: The downside is the other thread will run on and consume resources for the remainder of its timeout even when you've given up waiting. IMPORTANT: To produce a correct program you must eventually `join()` the other thread to make sure it really does finish cleanly and thereby may absorb a last bit of delay. Because MQ is dealing with system wide resources you can't risk the JVM itself killing the thread when your `main()` ends or you may cause different parts of the application the same woe. If your thread isn't the `main()` just do that at the end of your `run()` method.

Comment: If your in the `main()` thread, you should add something to the end of `main()` that accesses a static list of not-yet-dead sub-threads. It needs to tell all of them to "stop cleanly" in one loop and `join()` the threads in a second loop. You need to be careful to add each thread to the collection during construction but can't remove themselves at the end of `run()` because a `Thread` itself has tear-down code after `run()`. So if you repeatedly do this you might need another thread to manage the threads or look at `ThreadGroup`,

Comment: It might sound like a load of work. But it isn't really. MQ is a resource outside your JVM (and even server). You can't risk corrupting it because your code doesn't tidy up after itself.

Comment: @Persixty It does seem like a load of work, and I don't think it would prevent the stuck threads. The thread itself is stuck, it cannot exit(not even interrupt), and I think it would just keep a few more threads alive..

Comment: If the timeout isn't 'infinite' it will work. Even if it's infinite you'd ordinarily expect any good API to *eventually* succeed or return an error. But if `Thread#stop()` doesn't work (not surprised). The API isn't `Thread#interrupt()` friendly and it may run forever. The API doesn't offer some 'quit' protocol of it's own, there's a problem. Ask another Question here and be clearer about your technology stack and the precise problem. Your problem isn't with the principles of how to 'quit' threads in general. It's very domain specific to MQ.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread#stop()` is deprecated as 'inherently unsafe' and should be avoided if at all possible.

It's a source of instability and corruption and may fail anyway!

It actually causes a `ThreadDeath` exception to be throw in the target thread.
The authors of whatever code it pops into are unlikely to have expected that outcome.
Objects may be in an inconsistent state, external resources may be held and get leaked, files may be incompletely written.

There are ways of handling unexpected errors but in practice most code is written assuming it knows which exceptions might be thrown and not in anticipation for such a 'surprise'.

Given `ThreadDeath` is a `Throwable` any `catch(Throwable t)` will catch it and again, unless great care was taken in every piece of code the thread might execute (unrealistic) `ThreadDeath` might just get absorbed and not end the thread.

The correct way to handle this is declare an atomic variable (usually as part of the `Runnable` that represents the task.

```
AtomicBoolean stopThread=new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

Then write the loop as:

```
 while (!stopThread.get()) {
     System.out.println(1);
 }
```

And provide a method:

```
public void stopThread(){
    stopThread.set(true);
}
```

Alternatively you can use `interrupt()` and check `interrupted()`. These are cleaner methods provided in the `Thread` class. `interrupted()` has the behaviour of clearing the flag when called. That's not always helpful and while the flag can be examined by `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` the 'checking the flag clears it' behaviour can be unhelpful and also suffers some of the issues of `stop()` because it can cause "surprising" exceptions to be throw at points other code has never anticipated. The right approach is to use your own flag and be in full control of where the process decides to quit.

Take your pick.

See also: [Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

---

Ever wondered why when you click 'Cancel' on some concurrent process you are often made to wait ages for it to respond?
This is why. The task needs to come to a well defined point and do any necessary clean up to terminate in a well defined way.

Think of `Thread#stop()` as like stopping a cyclist by kicking them off their bike. The method here waves a red flag at them and they then come to a halt as swiftly as they safely can.

`Thread#stop()` should never have been in Java and you should never use it.
You get away with it in development and small systems. It causes havoc in large production environments. 
It's not just deprecated as 'not recommended' it is 'inherently unsafe' do not use it. 
It's been deprecated for years and its disappointing that some 'removal date' has never been advertised.

Here's an example that uses either `Thread#stop()` or `interrupt()` depending on whether you opt for being dangerous.

```
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.Thread;

class Ideone
{

    private static boolean beDangerous=true;//Indicates if we're going to use the Thread#stop().... 

    //This main method uses either stop() or interrupt() depending on the option.
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        PrimeFactor factor=new PrimeFactor();
        try{
    for(int i=1;i<30;++i){
        Thread thrd=new Thread(new Primer(factor));
        thrd.start();

        Thread.sleep(10);//Represents some concurrent processing...

        if(beDangerous){
            thrd.stop();
        }else{
            thrd.interrupt();
        }
        thrd.join();
        if(!factor.check()){
            System.out.println("Oops at "+i);
        }
    }
        }catch(Throwable t){
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }

    //This class just hammers the PrimeFactor object until interrupt()ed (or stop()ed).
    private static class Primer implements Runnable {

        private PrimeFactor factor;

        public Primer(PrimeFactor ifactor){
            factor=ifactor;
        }


        public void run(){
            int i=1;
            while(!Thread.interrupted()){   
                factor.set(i++);    
        }
           }
    }

    //Don't worry about this bit too much.
    //It's a class that does a non-trivial calculation and that's all we need to know.
    //"You're not expected to understand this". If you don't get the joke, Google it.

    //This class calculates the largest prime factor of some given number.
    //Here it represents a class that ensures internal consistency using synchronized.
    //But if we use Thread#stop() this apprently thread-safe class will be broken.
    private static class PrimeFactor {
        private long num;
        private long prime;

        public static long getFactor(long num){
            if(num<=1){
               return num;
            }
            long temp=num;
            long factor=2;
            for(int i=2;temp!=1;++i){
                if(temp%i==0){
                    factor=i;
                    do{
                        temp=temp/i;
                    }while(temp%i==0);
                }   
            }
            return factor;
        } 

        public synchronized void set(long value){
            num=value;
            prime=getFactor(value);
        }

        public synchronized boolean check(){
            return prime==getFactor(num);
        }
    }   
}
```

Typical partial output:

```
Oops at 1
Oops at 2
Oops at 3
Oops at 6
Oops at 8
```

Notice that the `PrimeFactor` class can be described as thread-safe. All it's methods are `synchronized`. Imagine it's in some library. It's unrealistic to expect "thread-safe" to mean `Thread#stop()`-safe and the only way to do that would be intrusive. Putting calls to it in a  `try-catch(ThreadDeath tde)` block won't fix anything. The damage will have been down before it's caught.

Don't convince yourself that changing `set()` to the following solves it:

```
public synchronized void set(long value){
    long temp=getFactor(value);
    num=value;
    prime=temp;
}
```

First and foremost the the `ThreadDeath` exception could throw during the assignments so all that does is potentially shorten the odds on the Race Condition. It hasn't been negated. Never make "how likely is that to happen" arguments about race conditions. Programs call methods billions of times so billion to one-shots come up regularly.

To use `Thread#stop()` you can essentially never use any library objects including `java.*` and jump through hoops to handle `ThreadDeath` everywhere in your code and almost certainly eventually fail anyway.

Comment: As I've stated before, this could help if the function executing the while loop would be accessible to me. Unfortunately I've no way of editing this function. So that's why I need to just kill the thread

Comment: @AntilKarev So long as you're aware your code is unsafe and can't be made safe.  The answer is - find out how the framework lets you stop it cleanly or don't use that framework. No credible third-party software forces you to do things that way. Raise a question in some user forum or talk to the original author. Just don't think you've fixed anything. It's just broken in a different and unpredictable way. In multi-threading that is usually a worse place to be. I know you said you can't touch that. Sounds like you can't fix it then.

Comment: @AntilKarev What is the 'jar IBM have created'? It's below their usual standard to dump crap like that on you. I hope you've missed the right answer and if not you're not paying money for it.

Comment: well, it's ibm mq client jar. Unfortunately it's already embedded in the company I work in and we can't move to JMS, so currently I need to find a solution for this.

Comment: @AntilKarev MQ is flagship professional quality stuff. I'm not familiar with it's API but I'm sure you or your company are using it wrong if the answer seems to be `Thread#stop()` or your company has included a way to stop it properly and you just haven't been told or found it yet. There's no way the IBM SE's think `thread.stop();` is valid code and wouldn't force you to use it.

Comment: well, when instantiating a new MQQueueManager and random network problems, it could get the thread stuck... There is some timeout I can set, but unfortunately this configuration is set globally for every application that is running on the machine, causing the same timeout for two possible running applications on the machine. But I need a run-time configurable timeout. So, the API is not so supportive, and actually even when I use `Thread#stop()` it eventually causes an erasure of the class from memory by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

In java there is no official way of killing thread. This is bug. (no need to argue with it here) Thread#stop() should not be deprecated. It may be improved that it cannot be consumed. Even now it will work most of the time just fine.

Right now, if I write function which will be executed with kill need, I would start new thread and joint to it with timeout or other disconnect mechanism. This will make your code to continue like main thread was killed. Problem is that main thread is still running. All resources are still in use. This is still better than application being frozen. Calling thread.interrupt() is first step but it this does not work using thread.stop() is adequate here. It won't make things worse.

If you really must kill the thread, only way would be to start another jvm via jni, run unsafe code there and use linux kill -9 to stop the whole process if needed.

I believe killing thread is perfectly possible, only jvm developers didn't care enough. I get into this situation all the time and answers like don't use any libraries, fix all foreign code, write your own language or live with it are just frustrating.

Comment: I feel ur pain 